# OpenCV compilation with MinGW on Windows Linux Subsystem

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw

I am trying to build and OpenCV project on a Windows Linux Subsystem with MinGW but I keep getting errors, most of them are cannot find -lopencv_core and similar. I can successfully compile with

> g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

for linux, but if I try to use

> x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

I get the errors I mentioned before. Has anyone had any success on compiling OpenCV for MinGW?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(void )
{
   //Capture stream from webcam.
   cv::VideoCapture capture(0);

   //Check if we can get the webcam stream.
   if(!capture.isOpened())
   {
      std::cout << "Could not open camera" << std::endl;
      return -1;
   }

   //OpenCV saves detection rules as something called a CascadeClassifier which
   //    can be used to detect objects in images.
   cv::CascadeClassifier faceCascade;

   //We'll load the lbpcascade_frontalface.xml containing the rules to detect faces.
   //The file should be right next to the binary.
   if(!faceCascade.load("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"))
   {
      std::cout << "Failed to load cascade classifier" << std::endl;
      return -1;
   }

   while (true)
   {
      //This variable will hold the image from the camera.
      cv::Mat cameraFrame;

      //Read an image from the camera.
      capture.read(cameraFrame);

      //This vector will hold the rectangle coordinates to a detection inside the image.
      std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

      //This function detects the faces in the image and
      // places the rectangles of the faces in the vector.
      //See the detectMultiScale() documentation for more details
      // about the rest of the parameters.
      faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        cameraFrame, 
        faces, 
        1.09, 
        3,
        0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,
        cv::Size(30, 30));

      //Here we draw the rectangles onto the image with a red border of thikness 2.
      for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
            cv::rectangle(cameraFrame, faces[i], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);

      //Here we show the drawn image in a named window called "output".
      cv::imshow("output", cameraFrame);

      //Waits 50 miliseconds for key press, returns -1 if no key is pressed during that time
      if (cv::waitKey(50) >= 0)
          break;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks